# Aquire Token with ADAL.Net throws Unknown User Type for Managed AD Account

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to call a web (api) service using a OAuth2 token based on a AAD managed user account logged in to an AAD joined machine using ADAL.Net - specifically using this example:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-Integrated-authentication-on-Windows-(Kerberos)

However I keep getting the exception: Unknown User Type

In my setup I have logged onto a machine inside an AAD private network with a synced AAD user account. I then run the example code using WindowsAuthentication.

After some debugging I can narrow the exception to be thrown from this method in ADAL.Net

```
protected internal /* internal for test only */ override async Task PreTokenRequestAsync()
    {
        await base.PreTokenRequestAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (!SupportADFS)
        {
            var userRealmResponse = await _commonNonInteractiveHandler.QueryUserRealmDataAsync(Authenticator.UserRealmUriPrefix)
               .ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (string.Equals(userRealmResponse.AccountType, "federated", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                WsTrustResponse wsTrustResponse = await _commonNonInteractiveHandler.PerformWsTrustMexExchangeAsync(
                    userRealmResponse.FederationMetadataUrl,
                    userRealmResponse.CloudAudienceUrn,
                    UserAuthType.IntegratedAuth).ConfigureAwait(false);

                // We assume that if the response token type is not SAML 1.1, it is SAML 2
                _userAssertion = new UserAssertion(wsTrustResponse.Token, (wsTrustResponse.TokenType == WsTrustResponse.Saml1Assertion) ? OAuthGrantType.Saml11Bearer : OAuthGrantType.Saml20Bearer);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new AdalException(AdalError.UnknownUserType);
            }
        }
    }
```

Since everything in my setup is managed with AAD I do not see why the user account type needs to be "federated" in order for a token to be retrieved.

So I suspect that I need to get my token in another way!?
Any help will be appreciated ;)

Comment: Thanks for your effort on debugging! This kind of finding would better be in an issue in [ADAL .Net github repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet). We will investigate it.

Comment: Well I gues its a design issue and the above code goes only for a federated setup.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating we found that the above code (ADAL.Net) can only be used with a federated setup.

Federation means that you have an on premise network - which holds your windows user accounts - connected to an Azure AD network - which then "federates" these accounts to Azure AD. However it would be good to have a member of the ADAL team to comment on this.

Obtaining a token for a windows user account in a pure Azure AD (Managed setup) can supposedly be done using this code:

```
var connString = $"RunAs=App;AppId={appId};TenantId={tenantId};AppKey={appKey};";
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider(connString2);
var accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(service, tenantId).Result;
```

which is descripbed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#running-the-application-using-managed-identity

Again its not that well documented so any clarity from microsoft would be good.